# iOS local HTTP server clear communication

Tags: ios, swift, http, security, wkwebview

I'm using GCDWebServer as a local HTTP server, serving data.
Another part of my application base on a WKWebView consume this data.

So while the data is travelling between the two, it's unencrypted and available to anyone (correct me if I'm wrong)? How dangerous would that be, on a non jailbroken iOS device?

Problem:

- GCDWebServer doesn't support HTTPS : "What's not supported (but not really required from an embedded HTTP server): - HTTPS / - Keep Alive"
- WKWebViews doesn't allow you to intercept incoming data for pre-treatment. "WKWebView makes requests and renders content out-of-process, meaning your app does not hear the requests they make"

Any solution other than picking a new local WebServer?

Comment: You want to use it in your local network only?

Comment: No, it would be a regular app

Comment: Then it's not very secure. You could easily get the Data from this connection

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? Let's say the data transiting is also not very sensitive, could you describe the risks?

Comment: The risk depends on the data you send. If it's not sensitiv you are good to go. You are the only person who can judge that. Just keep in mind that it is possible to get the data.

Comment: @JonasSchafft Yes I understand, my question was not formulated correctly. My meaning was: how complicated would it be to get that data?

Comment: Ah okay, i understand. If you can describe your application a little more i could tell you how easy it would be. Right now i just know you have a local webserver and a WKWebView. But you said as another part of your application? I don't see the purpose behind that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153927/discussion-between-alexandre-camilleri-and-jonas-schafft).